# Opening a file in c which is in diffrent location

Tags: c, fopen

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


uid_t ruid=-1, euid=-1, suid=-1;



int main() {
FILE *fh = fopen("file.txt", "r");
char c;
while ((c = fgetc(fh)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", c);
}
return 0;
```

}

So guys I have to open this file using c fopen command but I have to specify at which location the file actually is. That is for example the above file.txt is not at the location where is program is being executed but it is at a diffrent location, for example the above file.txt is at /home/my_user_name and the place where the program is being executed is /home/my_user/anyfolder.
So I want to know how to specify the location of the file in the program.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Note: `c` should be an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FILE *fh = fopen("../file.txt", "r");
```

In case you don't know how to specify a path.
You could also do something like this:

```
char path[] = "../";  // or "/home/my_user_name/"
char file[] = "file.txt";
char full[256];

snprintf(full, sizeof(full), "%s%s", path, file);
FILE *fh = fopen(full, "r");
```

But don't forget error handling.

edit: with error checking:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    char path[] = "../";   // or "/home/my_user_name/"
    char file[] = "file.txt";
    char full[256];

    snprintf(full, sizeof(full), "%s%s", path, file);

    FILE *fh = fopen(full, "r");

    if (fh != NULL) {
        while ((c = fgetc(fh)) != EOF) {
            printf("%c", c);
        }
        fclose(fh);
    } else {
        printf("could not open file");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply specify the path.....

`fopen("/path/to/file.txt", "r")`

Comment: Hey, but it says segmentation fault

Comment: Then add a test to see if the `fopen` was successful before attempting to read from it!

Comment: I am a newbie can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: see my answer `FILE *fh = fopen("../file.txt", "r");` and make sure that the file is at the correct place and has the correct name.  To test if it was successful, just check if the return value of `fopen` is not null

Answer (score 1):

You could either use /home/my_user_name/file.txt as argument instead of file.txt:

```
FILE *fh = fopen("/home/my_user_name/file.txt", "r");
```

Or you could use a relative path (I wouldn't recommend this since this would require your program to be in a certain location to function correctly) :

```
FILE *fh = fopen("../file.txt", "r");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the path name: `fopen("/path/to/file.txt", "r")`.

If you want to check for error, just check the return value. Like this:

```
FILE *fh = fopen("/path/to/file.txt", "r");

if (fh == NULL) {
    // print error
    // exit program if you want to.
}
```

You can exit a program using the `exit` function. In this case, you want to exit because of an error, so do `exit (1);`

Answer (score 0):

Thats how u can check if the file was opened successfully.

```
FILE * pFile;

pFile = fopen ("test.txt","r");
if (pFile!=NULL)    //check if file was opened successfully
{
    //do stuff
}
return 0;
```